# C# bindinglist made of bindinglists

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, bindinglist

Is there a simple way to have a bindinglist composed of several bindinglists? i.e. that is the "view" of the lists.

That is to say: I have 3 lists (list1,list2,list3). I want a list that is always the union of the 3 listx (we can suppose that no object is contained in 2 different lists).

Certainly, I can succeed in using the ListChange property but maybe there is a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would need to create your own type, implement `IList`, `IBindingList` (and ideally `IBindingListView`), and optionally `ICancelAddNew` and `IRaiseItemChangedEvents`. You'd also need either a public non-object indexer (`public T this[int index] {get;}`) or `ITypedList`.

From having done things *similar* to this, I strongly advise you; don't, unless this is *really* important. It would be more pragmatic to copy the references into a new `BindingList<>`.

Also; with new items; which list would it go into?

Comment: I only want the view of the inner list, new items will be directly added to one of the inner list

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) class?

Depending on what you're trying to do, it might help: its purpose is to combine multiple collections into a single collection (typically for display/binding purposes).  So, you could create a `CompositeCollection` and add your three `BindingList` instances to it.  The `CompositeCollection` will automatically update to include the members of the "child" lists.

Comment: You can build the `CompositeCollection` in code or in Xaml, too.  It can be quite flexible!